# use conditions after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe df

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    data=[["A", "Man"], ["A", "Woman"], ["A", "Man"], ["A", "Man"], ["B", "Woman"]],
    columns=["category", "gender"],
)

df
  category gender
0        A    Man
1        A  Woman
2        A    Man
3        A    Man
4        B  Woman
```

and I count how many men and women are in each category

```
grouped = df.groupby(by=["category", "gender"])["gender"].count()

grouped
category  gender
A         Man       3
          Woman     1
B         Woman     1
Name: gender, dtype: int64
```

how can I get a list of categories for which both men and women are more than 1?

```
category_list = [A]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

```
s = df.groupby('category')['gender'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

s[s.ge(1).all(1)]
```

gives you

```
gender    Man  Woman
category            
A           3      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just convert the result to a dataframe and then apply query filter:

```
pandas.DataFrame(grouped).query("gender > 1")

                    gender
category    gender  
A              Man       3
```

Or you can directly do:

```
grouped[grouped > 1]
```